# Custom data send with order into backend

Tags: admin, checkout, orders, cart

I am trying to send order programmaticaly and I want to send with this order a custom information about user-uploaded image that could be visible in admin backend.

Here is my simple code:

```
$image = 'uploads/123193284234.jpg';
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$params = array(
    'product' => 37,
    'qty' => 1,
    'options' => array(
        371 => array(
            'user-uploaded-image' => $image // the info I want to send with order
        )   
    )
);
$cart->addProduct(37, $params);
$cart->save();
```

This code works, now, I want the user-uploaded-image to be displayed in admin backened in order detail as new custom field like this:

[image]

Thanks for every suggestions ( plugin, workflow to use ) especially about the part of how to add custom field to order-detail view in admin backend.

Answer (score 2):

Create a layout update in *app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\msd.xml* to add a tab in the admin order view:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">            
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
            <action method="addTab"><name>user_uploaded_image</name><block>msd/adminhtml_sales_order_view_tab_useruploadedimage</block></action>                                                            
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
</layout>
```

I used the module name *msd* for MageStackDay, which you need to replace with your module name.

The information of the uploaded image can be found in the *order_item* within the *order* object. So first, you need find the *order_item* that matches the *product_id* 37. Then look up the image info in the *product_options*. Create this block:

```
class Kiat_Msd_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Useruploadedimage
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Abstract
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{      
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();        
        $this->setTemplate('msd/sales/order/view/tab/useruploadimage.phtml');     }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return Mage::registry('current_order');
    }

    public function getImagePaths()
    {
        $imagePaths = array();
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getProductId() == 37) {
                $options = $item->getProductOptions();
                $imagePaths[$item->getId()] = $options[371]['order_path'];
            }
        }
        return $imagePaths;
    }


    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return $this->__('User Uploaded Image');
    }

    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->__('User Uploaded Image');
    }

    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in *msd/sales/order/view/tab/useruploadimage.phtml*, you can output the images:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getImagePaths() as $imagePath) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB) . substr($imagePath, 1); ?>">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```